# How to define firebase service Provider in Ionic 2

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angular2-services

I'm new to ionic and I neeed to upload images to my firebase storage.
I already done with the database records and angularfire2 has been used.
but when it comes to firebase storage needs to initilize the firebase config again.(**no firebase app '[default]' has been created**).

then i defined it again and successfully uploaded.

but when its defined twices it says

**Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists (app/duplicate-app).
after restart the app**

can anyone tellme how to define a provider for firebase service then i can use import it when i need.
Thanks in advance

Comment: i need to use service here

Comment: Why do you need to do it twice? There is no angularfire2 storage support yet.So you must use JS SDK for that.